# Editor And ReadOnly Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have simple edit form, where you can edit user profile, but you cannot edit username.

So instead this code:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.username)
```

I use this line:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.username, new {disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

This works fine, but, I cannot save other fields which are "EditorFor"

e.g. I have column Customers, so one user can have one or more customers, so if I make change in edit, e.g. add new user to customer, and then when I click save, it does not save it. But if I change code again to @Html.EditorFor(model => model.username) then it save it...

Any idea how to fiks this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a read only textbox is not sent back (value is not in POSTed datas).

So if you want to have a readonly textbox AND have the value of username in POSTed datas, you'll have to add a

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.username)
```

But... if you just wanna display them, you should just manage that in your controller (don't try to update username... as you don't wanna update username).